# Unable to show Hindi(Unicode) characters in BIRT generated PDF

Tags: pdf, unicode, fonts, birt

BIRT is unable to render Hindi language characters in generated PDF file. The same design file, when rendered as Word document or HTML or any other format, I am able to see the unicode characters.

I have set Arial Unicode MS as the font type in the design file and tried with few samples from google translate. Please let me know if I'm missing anything.

Thank you.

Comment: It might be the PDF, take a look at this simular issue with Korean http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/forum/index.php/topic/28963-in-pdf-korean-characters-are-broken/

Comment: New question at http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/forum/index.php/topic/28986-devanagarihindi-font-not-getting-rendered-for-pdf/ Devanagari(Hindi) font as a PDF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most probable BIRT can't find correct font files.

You have to configure pdf fonts correctly (see. file fontsconfig.xml).

I've similar issue with Cyrillic and Chinese fonts.

What I fixed in the file:

```
...
    <font-paths>
        <path path="fonts" />

        <!--path path="C:/windows/fonts" />
        <path path="d:/windows/fonts" />
        ...
        <path path="/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType" /-->
</font-paths>
```

Create fonts folder and put all necessary fonts (a bit tricky question is where fonts folder must be. It depends how you're using BIRT).

Optionally you can put correct font files in JRE/lib/fonts folder you're using.

Comment: I am trying to run the report directly from eclipse
Run -> View report as PDF.

I have looked all over the internet and finally got confused if my fontConfig.xml is correct or not. 

The font I am using is present in windows fonts folder and the path is present in the config xml under eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.fonts_4.2.1.v20120820 folder.

Kindly validate if all these are proper.

Comment: Just try to copy correct font files to your JRE/lib/fonts folder and try again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on JavaFx Desktop App.It will work. 
If you are using BIRT viewer deployment using `fontsConfig.xml` because all configs are bundled in `org.eclipse.birt.runtime_VERSION-XXX.jar`

So you can use this way just override `fontConfig_Pdf.xml` file and add your Font in this file

```
<composite-font>
<font font-family="mangal" catalog="Western"/>
</composite-font>
```

and after that add this line code in your BIRTserviceImpl Class where you are setting the RuntimeEngine

```
 EngineConfig conf = null;
 conf.setFontConfig(new File("fontsConfig_pdf_win.xml").toURL());
 conf.setEngineHome("{dir}/birt-runtime-4_4_1/ReportEngine");
 eng = new ReportEngine(conf);
```

this line will help to change runtime fonts config and 
copy your hindi fonts and paste into `jre/lib/Fonts` and `C:/windows/Fonts` also